# Jquery: accordion menu slideDown and slideUp

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I have this code:

```
<ul class="main">
    <li><a href="#">main menu1<span class="open"> </span></a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu5</a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
    <li><a href="#">main menu2<span class="open">  </span></a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu5</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

and this jquery for accordion menu

```
     var submenu = $('.submenu').hide();

  $('.open').click(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $target =  $this.parent().next();

      if(!$this.hasClass('close')){
         $('.open').removeClass('close');
         submenu.slideUp();
         $this.addClass('close');
         $target.slideDown();
      }
  });
```

And it works like this, clicking on the button in the right, its `submenu` is sliding down, and the others are sliding up.

I want  when I click on it itself (I mean the button in the right, which submenu is currently open), its `submenu` sliding up too.

How can I do it?

[Here is the code in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLePd/25/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, use an `else` condition and simply use `$target.slideUp();`

```
if(!$this.hasClass('close')){
     $('.open').removeClass('close');
     submenu.slideUp();
     $this.addClass('close');
     $target.slideDown();
}else{
     $target.slideUp();
     $this.removeClass('close');
}
```

[Here's your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tBGE/)